# return the size of the directory (and sub-directory)

Tags: unix

in unix, how can I figure out the size of a directory (and its sub-directories), including any hidden files etc.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
du -h dirname
```

Answer (score 5):

I always use this spell :

`du -ch --max-depth=1`

It should give you all info you want

--
Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 3):

```
du -sh <dir_name>
```